# Final variable resolved as non final variable - java

Tags: java, rest

I have the following piece of code to use REST service to fetch user credentials.

```
public class Login extends FragmentActivity
{
    public void invokeWS(RequestParams params){

    final ResponseObj responseObj = new ResponseObj();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get("http://<ip>:<port>/RestService/login/dologin",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    responseObj.setResponse(response);
                }

                // When the response returned by REST has Http response code
                // other than '200'
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                        String content) {
                    responseObj.setContent(content);
                    responseObj.setStatusCode(statusCode);
                }
            }
        );
    }
    // rest of the logic
}
```

However i am getting the famous "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable defined in an enclosing scope" on the variable responseObj. My variale is final and hence should be accessible. What am i missing??

Comment: "What am i missing??" - a [MCVE] :)

Comment: To expand on davmac's comment, I am not able to reproduce this error with your code: https://ideone.com/CLbNaq

Comment: Unable to replicate on Java 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: Perhaps you are running old code. Make sure to refresh, clean and re-build.